# Cannot launch android app from Eclipse on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, osx-lion

I get an error Android Launch - your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application in eclipse.

In the error log, I get "System property http.nonproxyhosts has been set to local....by an external source. Plugin - org.eclipe.core.net

I cannot launch my apps in the emulator or onto the device. I was able to about 1 week ago.

I am running Mac OSX Lion 10.7.2. Latest version of eclipse. Android SDK r15. Java version 1.6.0_29.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the org.eclipse.core.net plugin? Why are you using it and what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Here's some more info about the plugin...

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fnet%2Fproxy%2Fpackage-summary.html

Comment: How do I disable it? How come it was able to run before?